# org-mode how to use custom command when exporting figures

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I am using a TeX style provided by my university which includes a special command to describe the source of a figure. For some unknown reason, they have decided to put the source and the caption in different positions. So we have an additional command named `\figsource`.

I am using the following lines to insert a figure into my org file:

```
#+LABEL: fig:myfigure
#+CAPTION:My caption
[[file:img/fig1.pdf]]
```

which is exported into latex:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{img/fig1.pdf}
\caption{My caption}  
\end{figure}
```

However, to use the additional command `\figsource` I need something like:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{img/fig1.pdf}
\caption{My caption}  
\figsource{Source: \cite{someone2015}}
\end{figure}
```

How can I get this from org?

I've already tried this `#+ATTR_LATEX: \figsource{Source: \cite{someone2015}}` without success.

Comment: My suggestion would be an [export filter](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#filter).

Answer (score 3):

***Method using an export filter***

Fleshing out the suggestion in my comment, here is an implementation of a "final output" filter that puts the extra stuff just before the `\end{figure}' - not sure  if the location makes a difference. Note however that the extra stuff is assumed to be a fixed string:

```
* Code                                                        :noexport:

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (require 'ox)
  (defun my-custom-figsource (contents backend info)
    (when (eq backend 'latex)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\end{figure}"
                                "\\\\figsource{Source: \\\\cite{someone2015}}\n\\\\end{figure}" contents)))

  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions #'my-custom-figsource)

#+end_src

* Figure

#+LABEL: fig:myfigure
#+CAPTION:My caption
[[file:img/fig1.png]]
```

which export to the following TeX fragment:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{img/fig1.png}
\caption{\label{fig:org6271d58}
My caption}
\figsource{Source: \cite{someone2015}}
\end{figure}
```

Dealing with different citations in the `\figsource` would be harder and I don't know how to do it off the top of my head.

***Method using #+ATTR_LATEX***

Alternatively, you could use the `:caption` attribute in an `#+ATTR_LATEX`:

```
* Figure

#+LABEL: fig:myfigure
#+CAPTION:My caption
#+ATTR_LATEX: :caption \caption{\label{fig:myfigure}My caption}\figsource{Source: \cite{foo}}
[[file:img/fig1.png]]
```

There is some duplication in setting the label but it is localized and fairly easy to take care of and the method allows you to use different source citations easily, but I'm not sure how it interacts with the org-mode generated labels.